# Workflow, getting all numbers between two values

Tags: workflow

we were using Nintex Workflow here. I need to get all numbers between two numbers. For example: I have `2` and `8` so I need `2,3,4,5,6,7,8`. I tried it with a Loop and a State-Machine but this is very slow, 5 minutes for every Iteration(cause of safe-looping, I am not allowed to disable it).

So I tried it with a Webrequest which calls a little JavaScript. The JS generates a String with all numbers. Is there a possibility to write this String back in the Workflow.

Or is there another way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Nintex questions are off topic here, you'll want to ask at http://connect.nintex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did a little workaround to bypass the safe-looping.

> Way 1

I made a State-Machine with Workflows. Each Workflow is a State. 
In pseudocode it looks something like this:

Workflow0:

```
set/get(i,end);
Workflow1(i,end);
```

Workflow1:

```
if(i<=end){
   Workflow2(i,end);
}else{
   end(Workflow1);
}
```

Workflow2:

```
do workflow action;
Workflow1(i++,end);
```

> Way 2

Html form to get the start and endnumber. Iterate with JavaScript and call the Workflow via HTTP POST Request with passing the actual number to the Workflow. So the Workflow needs only the actual number

It may causes high server load, so I take no responsibility for any damage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a web request, create a string variable or a collection variable and store the result in that variable and you can then use it later however you need.

Comment: How can I get the .js string variable into a string variable in the workflow?

Comment: The web request action has an option at the bottom to store the result in, create a variable and use that.